# Geometrical interpretation of the conjugacy of triangle groups.

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\triangle$ and $\triangle'$  be two hyperbolic triangles of respective angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and $\alpha',\beta',\gamma'$. Let us suppose that the triangle subgroups $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ and $(\alpha',\beta',\gamma')$ of $\mathbb{P}\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ are conjugated. What does it tell us about the triangles $\triangle$ and $\triangle'$?

Reciprocally, is there any condition we could impose on the triangles $\triangle$ and $\triangle'$ for the triangle groups $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ and $(\alpha',\beta',\gamma')$ to be conjugated?

Comment: Please define triangle groups.

Comment: @studiosus Let $f_{i}$, $i\in\{1,2,3\}$ be the reflection that fix every point of a side $l_{i}$ of a triangle $T$. The triangle group associated to $T$ is $\langle f_{3}\circ f_{1}, f_{1}\circ f_{2}, f_{2}\circ f_{3}\rangle$.

Comment: So you make no assumptions about the angles, like being of the form $\pi/k$. Then it is hard to say much.

Comment: @studiosus and what could we say assuming the angles to be of the form $\pi/k$?

Comment: Then groups are conjugate iff triangles are congruent.

Comment: @studiosus Could you give me a reference for that result? Thank you!

Comment: I do not know a reference but it is easy if you are familiar with the Poincaré  fundamental domain theorem. If you know what it is, I will write a proof.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39148/discussion-between-carlito-and-studiosus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the angles of your triangles are all of the form $\pi/n$, $n\in {\mathbb N} - \{1\}$, of course is allowed to be different for different angles and triangles. Given a triangle $T$ with angles of this form, consider first the reflection group $\Gamma=\Gamma_T< Isom(H^2)$ generated  by reflections in the edges of $T$. Then $T$ is a fudnamental polygon for this group. The images of the triangle $T$ under $\Gamma$ tile the hyperbolic plane $H^2$ so that no **$\Gamma$-wall** in $H^2$ crosses $T$; this is an immediate consequence of being a fundamental domain. (Here, walls in $H^2$ are fixed lines of reflections which belong to $\Gamma$.) Now, suppose that $T'$ is another fundamental triangle of $\Gamma$. Then, after applying an element of $\Gamma$ to $T'$, we may assume that interiors of $T$ and $T'$ have nonempty intersection. But, since $T$ does not cross any walls, it follows that $T=T'$.

Now, suppose that $\Gamma_{T}, \Gamma_{T'}$ are conjugate triangle reflection groups, $\Gamma_{T'}= g \Gamma_T g^{-1}, g\in Isom(H^2)$. Then $g^{-1}(T')$ is a fundamental triangle of $\Gamma$. By the above argument, it follows that $T, T'$ are congruent.

Now, your groups $\Delta$ (under the angle assumption I made above) are index 2 subgroups in the triangle reflection groups. However, one can show that each $\Delta$ is an index 2 subgroup of a unique triangle reflection group. Thus, $\Delta$ is conjugate to $\Delta'$ iff the triangles are congruent.